# DRF select_related and prefetch_related doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm try to decrease query counts for using **prefetch_related** and **select_related**. However, it seems doesn't work.

in **Match** Model have 5 ForeignKey fields, so when i get the query counts it will return 5. Also when i delete `def get_queryset` method in `MatchDetailAPIView`. The Api still work. ( e.g **127.0.0.1:8000/game/match/match-1** is working whether or not the `get_queryset` method.

I can't find where I'm doing wrong.

Models.py

```
    class Game(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        ...

    class Match(models.Model):
        name = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
        game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
        tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
        ....
```

serializers.py

```
 class MatchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Match
        fields = '__all__'
        #exclude = ['participant', ]
```

views.py

```
class MatchDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):

serializer_class = MatchSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset =Match.objects.all().prefetch_related('game_id')
    return queryset

def get_object(self):
    gameslug = self.kwargs.get('gameslug')
    slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
    # find the user
    game = Game.objects.get(slug=gameslug)

    return Match.objects.get(slug=slug, game__slug=game.slug)

def get_serilizer_context(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return {'request': self.request}
```

Comment: Please, explain what "it seems doesn't work" means. What are you trying to get as a result exactly - "decrease query counts" is too vague for us, how many do you expect ? how many do you have ? how can you tell ?

Comment: in **Match** Model have 5 ForeignKey fields, so when i get the query counts it will return 5. Also when i delete "def get_queryset" method in MatchDetailAPIView. The Api still work. ( e.g  http://127.0.0.1:8000/game/match/match-1 is working whether or not the "get_queryset" method.

Comment: Please edit your question so that others will also benefit the added clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You should use select_related for `ForeignKey` fields, since `prefetch_related` does the joining in Python, and `select_related` creates an SQL join.

You should also refer to the relationship by it's name, not the id of the ForeignKey ('game_id' vs. 'game'):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset =Match.objects.all().select_related('game')
    return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related), select_related should be used for foeign-key relationships. Also for [RetrieveAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview) override the get method.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    gameslug = self.kwargs.get('gameslug')
    slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
    game = Game.objects.get(slug=gameslug)

    return Match.objects.filter(slug=slug, game__slug=gameslug).select_related('game').first()
```